# OpenGL ES: Screenshot size is different in retina and non-retina devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am new in opengl es 2.0 development. The UIImage I got from screenshot looks good on non-retina devices (iphone 4 and ipad), but when I got screenshot from retina devices it seems enlarged. Here is the code I used.

```
-(UIImage *) glToUIImage {

  CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;

  // the reason I set the height and width up-side-down is because my 
  // screenshot captured in landscape mode.
  int image_height = (int)size.width; 
  int image_width  = (int)size.height;

  NSInteger myDataLength = image_width * image_height * 4;

  // allocate array and read pixels into it.
  GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
  glReadPixels(0, 0, image_width, image_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

  // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
  // there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
  GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
  for(int y = 0; y < image_height; y++)
 {
    for(int x = 0; x < image_width * 4; x++)
    {
        buffer2[(image_height - 1 - y) * image_width * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * image_width + x];
    }
}

  // make data provider with data.
  CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

  // prep the ingredients
  int bitsPerComponent = 8;
  int bitsPerPixel = 32;
  int bytesPerRow = 4 * image_width;
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
  CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

  // make the cgimage
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image_width, image_height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

  // then make the uiimage from that
  UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

  return myImage;
}

 // screenshot function, combined my opengl image with background image and
 // saved into Photos.
 -(UIImage*)screenshot
 {
  UIImage *image = [self glToUIImage];

  CGRect pos = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

  [image drawInRect:pos];
  [self.background.image drawInRect:pos];
  UIImage* final = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  // final picture I saved into Photos.
  return final;
}
```

Function is working, but the opengl image only shows part in retina devices, how to solve this problem. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes the view size is equal to pixels but it isn't. It is points. You need to convert to actual pixel size per device. UIScreen has a scale property for this.

Comment: So should I do something like this? UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale]);

Comment: You could do it a number of ways. One way is to adjust your size values by the scale. Do whatever works and is clear in your code when you need to read it later.

Comment: Awesome. You're welcome. For anybody doing similar on OSX, NSScreen has a similar API with slightly different name.